# How to implement charts for Salesforce android project

Tags: android, charts, salesforce

I am working on a salesforce android mobile project, I need to implement some charts for it. But the problem is, how to implement those charts? Is there any library for those charts or do I need to use some external libraries for it?

Thanks.

Comment: make some research and add the code that you have tried so far before asking any question.This type of Question always make negative impression. Instead of Asking this directly in Stackoverflow.if you have googled it , you might not have asked this question

Comment: I was trying to find a solution. But there is no more tutorial for the Salesforce. I just need to implement a chart without using external libraries. That's why I asked some help here.

Comment: I dont know what does SalesForce mean ? what actually you want is the Response of the Data , that is needed to be plotted. There are plenty of Library, the one mostly used is MPAndroid Chart .that is added in the below  Answer too.Have a look at this
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend using [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart). Here is a list of charts and graphs available.

- Bar chart
- Combined-Chart (bar- and linechart in this case)
- PieChart
- ScatterChart
- RadarChart

  etc. I have used MpAndroidChart in my projects and i found it to be easy and flexible to use.

Edit : If you want to create your own chart , you will need to extend the View class and draw stuff on the canvas.

Comment: Thank you so much for your prompt reply.